# run terraform apply from crontab

Tags: shell, cron, terraform, centos

I am try to run terraform init&plan&apply when a new VM boot,i already setup crontab like this:

@reboot username /home/username/script/initial.sh; /home/username/script/terraform-init.sh; /home/username/script/terraform-plan.sh; /home/username/script/terraform-apply.sh

1. initial.sh setup provider.tf file and it's worked fine.
2. terraform-init.sh is also fine, i can see .terraform folder and .terraform.lock.hcl file under target folder.
3. terraform-plan.sh is fine, i can see -out plan file in target folder.

but the last one terraform-apply.sh not work.
the script is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/terraform  
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

I also tried use terraform apply "/path/to/plan/file", but it still not work.

I can manual run ./terraform-apply.sh and it worked fine. it will output logs under TF_LOG_PATH, but when i reboot vm, no log output in TF_LOG_PATH file.

Does crontab can trigger terraform apply?

thanks

Comment: "not work." is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: thanks Marcin, i add export TF_LOG environment variable, it show logs when i manual run ./terraform-apply.sh, but when i reboot vm, i see no log output in it. It seem like terraform-apply.sh never triggered...

Comment: If you want the env var to persist over restarts, you probably want to export it in the same shell script.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i use profile to run terraform and terraform init and plan are worked fine, i don't know why terraform apply not triggered from crontab...

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everyone,i still don't know why but i add "@reboot ecs-user sleep 60 && " before my terraform apply script, and it worked!